# Solve an issue in a pure css dropdown menu

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I recently created a pure css drop-down menu using Google tutorials.

I have an issue though:

If I give a small margin to the 2nd level `ul`, when you hover on the gap between the `ul` and parent `li` drop-down fades away.

Is there any way to fix this not involving Javascript?

Refer to the demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/ba76n/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that margin is causing the mouse to drop the "mouseover" state, without it it works fine.

If you switch to `padding-top:.5em;` it should work as expected. This is because margin is on the outside of block elements while padding is on the inside.

Comment: thanks for the guidance. but i think it is really weird. because the margin which is outside of the element, still is inside the parent element. so while we're hovering on margin area, we are hovering no the parent element. do you have any thoughts on this ?

Comment: It's all box-model weirdness, check this out http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/30-the-css-layout-model-boxes-border/

Answer (score 2):

Use `padding-top` instead of `margin-top`.

See it working. http://jsfiddle.net/ba76n/5/

Answer (score 2):

use `padding-top` instead of `margin-top` since margin is applied outside of the block so when you try to select the sub-menu its come on the margin and the block is changed so the sub-menu disappears

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/ba76n/9/ updated your fiddle...hope it helps :)

( Just removed the margin top from the dropdown li and added a border )